# What scenarios force me to setup workarounds for ng-model in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Typically in almost all situations, I am able to setup ng-model on an element in the standard fashion as follows.

```
<textarea ng-model="MessageText"></textarea>
```

But sometimes ng-model does not update within the scope. I have to force it to work by doing this

```
<textarea ng-model="MessageText" ng-change="UpdateMessageTextScope(MessageText)" ></textarea>

$scope.UpdateMessageTextScope = function (MessageText) {
    $scope.MessageText = MessageText;
}
```

In the above setup, if I leave out the ng-change, ng-model appears to be very buggy. Adding {{MessageText}} to my html seems to indicate MessageText is properly updating, but when it comes time to submit data to an API, MessageText contain different data than what {{MessageText}} on the UI is showing me. By different data, I mean it only updates the ng-model value 1 time... if I type new data into the textarea, the UI output indicates it updated to the new value, but the scope is stuck using the original value.

It's not very frequent (1% or less), but I am confused as to what causes this in the first place.

Comment: AHHHH *covers eyes* Why is your JS code CamelCased with a leading capital letter? This isn't C#.

Comment: Try using a view model for the data bound to your view. Something like `$scope.vm = {}` and `<textarea ng-model="vm.messageText"...`

Comment: @TomSlick, I thought camelCase necessarily meant that the first letter is not capitalized (so it looks like a camel) :). And PascalCase is what you referred to

Comment: Since you mentioned that it only updates the first time, but not subsequent times, then what do you mean by "1% or less"? Can you not consistently reproduce the error?

Comment: By 1%, I mean it only affects 1% of my ng-model use cases. If it's not working for one element, it consistently will not work for that element until I add in the ng-change event for that specific case.

Comment: @NewDev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CamelCase.svg can be either caps or not. But yeah, Pascal is always caps.